# How to access one application.properties in microservices

Tags: spring, microservices

how is the file application.properties handled in microservices? Is there a way to have one global application.properties file that all microservices can access?

Comment: In a microservice architecture, microservices do not assume eachother's programming language. Wouldn't this break that?

Answer (score 1):

Application.properties or Application.yaml used for loading the configuration on startup and inject the property value in variable. Like **keyStorePath** variable will be injected with value defined in properties file.

**Java Code**

```
@Value("${java.keystore.path}")
    private String keyStorePath;
```

**application.properties**

```
java:
 keystore:
  path: /KeyStore.jks
```

Yes, You can use centralized configurations that can be used by all microservice, Create Config Server annoted with **@EnableConfigServer** that will hold configurations for all microservice(instead of local application.properties all microservice on start will come to config server for configuration just we need to provide config server url so that microservices can communicate with config server on startup and have required data).

**Config Server Main Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.abc.*"})
public class ConfigApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Property file in config Server**

```
 java:
     keystore:
      path: /KeyStore.jks
```

**Property File in Microservice** that will hold the url of Config Server

```
# MicroServices Properties
spring:
  application:
     name: Microservice1
  profiles:
    active: rds
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
      fail-fast: true
      password: test@123
      username: user
```